# Java - Solving WindowPeer warning

Tags: java, warnings

When I compile my below java code,

```
Window w = c instanceof Window ? (Window) c : SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(c);
WindowPeer peer = (WindowPeer) w.getPeer();
```

I'm getting below warning message:

```
warning: WindowPeer is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?
I'm using JDK 1.6 and I tried 1.7 also.

Comment: "

The peer interfaces are intended only for use in porting the AWT. They are not intended for use by application developers, and developers should not implement peers nor invoke any of the peer methods directly on the peer instances. "

Comment: 1. Why do you use it? 2. Ask how you can do this without WindowPeer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to suppress the warning.
Suppressing the warning is not recommended, though, and the warning message text tells you why.

Approach #1 (the simplest) is to run

```
javac -XDignore.symbol.file ...
```

which will compile your program against Sun's internal `rt.jar` rather than the public-facing symbol file `ct.sym`.

Approach #2a is to run

```
javac -XDenableSunApiLintControl -Xlint:-sunapi ...
```

This still issues a "note" but not a warning.

Approach #2b is to suppress the warning and the note by writing

```
@SuppressWarnings("sunapi")
```

in the source code, but this still requires you to run javac as follows:

```
javac -XDenableSunApiLintControl ...
```

Comment: `-XDenableSunApiLintControl -Xlint:-sunapi` not working with Java 9